# Open Ethereum wallet application from browser

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency

To open a wallet application and exchange bitcoin, you just have to redirect to this link:

`href="bitcoin:${address}?amount=${amount}"`

But what's the prefix for Eth? ethereum doesn't work.